# %1 is not a valid Win32 application.. Sqlite3 in Electron app

Tags: sqlite, electron

I’m trying to get sqlite3 to work in an electron app running on Windows7 and 10. Running the following command, I was able to create `electron-v1.7-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node`

```
   cd node_modules/sqlite3 && sudo npm install nan 
&& sudo npm run prepublish && sudo node-gyp configure --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=…/lib/binding/electron-v1.7-win32-x64 
&& node-gyp rebuild --target=1.6.11 --arch=x64 --target_platform=win32 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell 
--module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=…/lib/binding/electron-v1.7-win32-x64
```

However, I get `Uncaught Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. \\?\c:\folder\ppt_win32-x64\resources\app\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v1.7-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node.`

My node version is v7.4.0. Electron v1.6.11.

Comment: I learned that Windows binding can be compiled on Windows only. I was trying to do it on mac. It worked when I did it on Windows with VS 2015 installed to provide a C++ compiler.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to compile for windows from mi Mac and I had that problem too, but after some readings I figured out how to proceed, and after all I can say that I got it. Yesterday I spent all day setting up a windows virtual machine in my (other) Linux laptop (I used my linux laptop just because my mac was exhausted in storage...). I was having too a problem with the preloadScript from electron main process in windows, Cant found the script, it was solved too.

Anyway, I think the library node printer from @tojocky is well maintained, in other hand in the electron-builder documentation they say that you should compile in native for natural reasons. Once you will have it, you'll see that it's a cleaner and pragmatic solution ...

This was my entire process, I hope it helps to someone having the same issue:

- Get VirtualBox (or Parallels but is not free)
- Get iso for W10
- Create a VM with this W10 iso, and you should give to this VM some storage (because some dependency that you'll need to compile), I have assigned 60gb to this VM
- Once I had that VM running, I just installed in that machine Visual Studio 2017 (with their build-tools included, it's necessary)
- And then, I used CMD to make the rest
- Install NodeJS (and NPM, but it comes with)
- Install node-gyp globally
- Install Python 2.7
- Clone your project from git (in my case)
- npm i (in your project), you should have as npm dependency in your package.json the module electron-builder of course. (here I had some troubles because when node-gyp tried to rebuild printer to generate the binary for windows it was failing, this was because it was imposible to find the python executable, so if you face this problem you should add it like:npm config set python "c:\Python27\python.exe" in my case )
- Then try again npm i and Voila!

If you still having error you can rebuild the native dependency as well, run:

- node-gyp rebuild --target=YOUR_ELECTRON_TARGET[eg: 1.8.4] --arch=YOUR_ARCH_TARGET[eg: x64 | ia32] --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell

After all, you should make the build using electron-builder, in my case my npm script command was build --win --x64 but you can use the --ia32 flag as well for 32bits